# Run Async method within puppeteer event

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am working with the puppeteer js library and I've reached a stumble. 
I need to run an async function within the page.on('request') event. Like so:

```
async function main(){
    page.on('request'){
        await sub()
    }
}

async function sub(){
    await page.goto(url)
}
```

When I run the above code: I get an error

```
await sub();
^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

Please help

Comment: You should include details like what you expect the code to do vs. what it's actually doing.

Comment: Sure thing. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `async` in callback method (+ you have a syntax problem):

```
async function main(){
    page.on('request', async () => {
        await sub()
    });
}

async function sub(){
    await page.goto(url)
}
```